# How-To: A form with a collection of forms which contains another collection

Tags: forms, symfony, orm

I have to create a simple system for some polls starting with 3 entities: `VotingSession`, `Question` and `Answer`.

Between `VotingSession` and `Question` is a One-To-Many relationship.
Between `Question` and `Answer` is a One-To-Many relationship.

What I'm trying to achieve is the next scenario: *Answers can have multiple types. For examples, you can have radiobox inputs where you will choose one answer, you can have checkbox inputs where you will choose 1 or more items or text input fields where you will fill whatever you want.*

I already pass a **VotingSession** object to the first form and entire form is displayed perfectly, so there's no problem here. What I discovered is that when I access `$builder->getData()` inside the `buildForm()` method on `QuestionForm` I get value `NULL`, even form is filled.

My idea is to try to achieve my goal based on passed value, but I can't do that.

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong or any advice?

I have the following forms:

**VotingSessionForm**:

```
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('questions', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type'     => QuestionForm::class,
        'by_reference'   => true,
        'prototype'      => true,
        'prototype_name' => '__question__',
        'entry_options'  => [
            'label' => false,
        ],
        'constraints'    => [
            new Valid(),
        ],
    ]);
}

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'error_bubbling' => false,
        'data_class'     => VotingSession::class,
    ]);
}
```

**QuestionForm**:

```
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('answers', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type'     => AnswerForm::class,
        'prototype'      => true,
        'prototype_name' => '__answers__',
        'entry_options'  => [
            'label' => false,
        ],
        'constraints'    => [
            new Valid(),
        ],
    ]);
}

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Question::class,
    ]);
}
```

**AnswerForm**:

```
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('label', TextType::class, [
            'label'    => false,
            'disabled' => true,
        ])
        ->add('value', NumberType::class, [
            'label'  => false,
            'mapped' => false,
        ]);
}

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Answer::class,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Form data [is not bound yet](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#the-form-workflow) at build time, you'll have to rely on form events. [This article](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) should cover your use case.

Comment: @msg I'll have a look! Thank you!